Chainlink VRF 2.5 fund subscription with native token programmatically
Anyone has an example of how to programmatically fund a Chainlink VRF (v2.5) subscription with ETH (native token)?
The example code only shows how to fund with LINK, see Create a subscription programmatically.

You can add this function in your SubscriptionManager contract:
function topUpSubscriptionWithNativeToken(uint256 amount)
    external
    payable
    onlyOwner
{
    if (msg.value < amount) {
        revert InsufficientValue(amount);
    }

    s_vrfCoordinator.fundSubscriptionWithNative{value: amount}(
        s_subscriptionId
    );
}

It will call the fundSubscriptionWithNative function of the SubscriptionAPI contract (as it's inherited by the VRFCoordinatorV2_5 contract). And, it requires the subscriptionId as a parameter and the amount to be attached as value.
